# Creating a calculation table from text file

Tags: python

`88 90 94 98 100 110 120
75 77 80 86 94 103 113
80 83 85 94 111 111 121
68 71 76 85 96 122 125
77 84 91 102 105 112 119
81 85 90 96 102 109 134`

Hi i am very new to computer programming in general and I need some help with my current project. I need to read numbers from a text file into a table and calculate the averages and max.This is what I currently have.

```
def main():
intro()
#sets variables
n1=[]
n2=[]
n3=[]
n4=[]
n5=[]
n6=[]
n7=[]
numlines = 0
filename = input("Enter the name of the data file: ")
print() #turnin
infile = open(filename,"r")


for line in infile:
    #splits the lines
    data = line.split()
    #takes vertical lines individually and converts them to integers
    n1.append(int(data[0]))
    n2.append(int(data[1]))
    n3.append(int(data[2]))
    n4.append(int(data[3]))
    n5.append(int(data[4]))
    n6.append(int(data[5]))
    n7.append(int(data[6]))
    datalist = n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6
#calculates the average speeds
n1av = (sum(n1))/len(n1)
n2av = (sum(n2))/len(n2)
n3av = (sum(n3))/len(n3)
n4av = (sum(n4))/len(n4)
n5av = (sum(n5))/len(n5)
n6av = (sum(n6))/len(n6)
n7av = (sum(n7))/len(n7)
#calculates the max speeds
n1max = max(n1)
n2max = max(n2)
n3max = max(n3)
n4max = max(n4)
n5max = max(n5)
n6max = max(n6)
n7max = max(n7)
#Calculates the average of the average speeds
Avgav = (n1av + n2av + n3av + n4av + n5av + n6av + n7av) / 7
#Calculates the average of the average max
Avmax = (n1max + n2max + n3max + n4max + n5max + n6max + n7max) /  7












#creates table
print(aver_speed)
print()
print(" "* 27, "Speed (MPH)")
print(" "*3,"Car   :", "{:6}".format(30),"{:6}".format(40),"{:6}".format(50)
      ,"{:6}".format(60),"{:6}".format(70),"{:6}".format(80),
      "{:6}".format(90)," :","{:14}".format ("Average Noise"))
print("-"*77)
for i in range(0,len(datalist)):
    print("{:6}".format(int("1")+1)," "*2,":", "{:6}".format (n1[i]), "{:6}".format (n2[i]), "{:6}".format (n3[i]),
    "{:6}".format (n4[i]),"{:6}".format (n5[i]),"{:6}".format (n6[i]),"{:6}".format (n7[i])," :", )
print("-"*77)
print(" ","Average","{:1}".format(":"), "{:8.1f}".format(n1av),"{:6.1f}".format(n2av),
      "{:6.1f}".format(n3av),"{:6.1f}".format(n4av),"{:6.1f}".format(n5av),"{:6.1f}".format(n6av),
      "{:6.1f}".format(n7av), "{:9.1f}".format(Avgav))
print()
print(" ","Maximum","{:1}".format(":"), "{:6}".format(n1max), "{:6}".format(n2max), "{:6}".format(n3max), "{:6}".format(n4max)
      , "{:6}".format(n5max), "{:6}".format(n6max), "{:6}".format(n7max),"{:11.1f}".format(Avmax))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Now that i have updated my code my table looks like this:

```
Car   :     30     40     50     60     70     80     90  : Average Noise
2    :     88     90     94     98    100    110    120  :
2    :     75     77     80     86     94    103    113  :
2    :     80     83     85     94    111    111    121  :
2    :     68     71     76     85     96    122    125  :
2    :     77     84     91    102    105    112    119  :
2    :     81     85     90     96    102    109    134  :
Average :  78.2   81.7   86.0   93.5  101.3  111.2  122.0      96.3
Maximum :  88     90     94    102    111    122    134       105.9
```

I've been trying to figure out the calculations for average noise and how to list the cars 1 through 6. I was unable to fi

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of code now. You can do this easier. If you want calculate by **strings**:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        list_of_speed = map(int, line.split())
        max_speed = max(list_of_speed)
        aver_speed = float(sum(list_of_speed))/len(list_of_speed)
```

If by **column**:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    l = map(lambda x: map(int, x.split()), f.readlines())

    for n in range(len(l[0])):
        list_of_speed = [value[n] for value in l]
        max_speed = max(list_of_speed)
        aver_speed = float(sum(list_of_speed))/len(list_of_speed)
```

Comment: The file can be iterated over directly, no need for `readlines()`, `for line in f:` will do (and is more pythonic).

Comment: I think the question was about getting data from each *column* of the file as one group and get sum and average on that group.  I believe that was why @Reilly Peters initialized six lists

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions i will give it a try.

Comment: It is giving me the following error when i try to use the first code: TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() function on a list and len() function gives the number of elements in the list.  So for average calculation you can simply do sum(n1)/float(len(n1)).

Try to use some dynamic way of keeping track of read data or calculate sum and avg on the fly and keep track of that data.  Not to discourage you but using six lists doesn't look so elegant.  Hope something similar to this might work:

```
from pprint import pprint

def main():
    # intro()
    filename = input("Enter the name of the data file:")
    infile = open(filename,"r")

    n = {} # a dictionary

    for line in infile:
        # apply typecasting on each element
        data = map(int, line.split()) 

        # add speeds into to a dictionary of lists
        # supports any number of data sets
        for i,d in enumerate(data):
            if i+1 in n:
                n[i+1].append(d)
            else:
                n[i+1] = [d]


    pprint (n) 

    # do whatever you want with the dictionary
    for d in n:
        print ("-" * 10)
        print (d)
        print (sum(n[d]))
        print (sum(n[d])/float(len(n[d])))


main()
```

For printing purposes you may want to use some thing like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable